# Ordered (natural insertion order) and threadsafe Java Map

Tags: java, multithreading, dictionary, java.util.concurrent

I have a legacy application in which they are using a ConcurrentHashMap. Now as we know that concurrentHasMap is unordered, but reading objects as they were originally inserted is a requirement. The code I have has been there for sometime on production, thus I am looking for quick alternatives to just replace the collection and which could give me ordering as well. Basically looking for a very non-invasive solution which leads to minimum code changes. I searched the Web and got ConcurrentSkipListMap as an alternative, but it wont work for me. Reason being, by default it orders on the natural ordering of the key, which will not work for me. As my keys are string and I need ordered to be based on insertion not how string keys will be naturally ordered in the map.

Please suggest some alternatives at the earliest.

Thanks
Anubhav

Comment: _it orders on the natural ordering of the key_ it is called `sorted`. Maybe you should use `LinkedHashMap (concurrentlinkedhashmap)`.

Comment: Here is a ConcurrentLinkedHashMap: https://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a `LinkedHashMap` to preserve insertion order and make it `synchronized` using the `Collections.synchronizedMap(Map map)` method.

```
public class Test {
  Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
  Map<String, String> test = Collections.synchronizedMap(map);

  public void test() {
    test.put("Z", "Zed");
    test.put("A", "Ay");
    for (String s : test.keySet()) {
      System.out.println(s);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      new Test().test();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
  }

}
```

This prints:

```
Z
A
```

as you require.

Comment: That is a significant change - iterations will need to be synchronized and CHM specific methods such as `putIfAbsent` won't be easily replaced.

Comment: @assylias - Agreed - this would only work if OP does not use those methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could re-order the keys yourself. Something like this might be possible. Note that this is not a complete solution, much extra work would be required to properly implement `ConcurrentMap`.

```
class InsertOrderedMap<K, V> implements ConcurrentMap<K,V> {
  // The actual map holding the data.
  Map<Integer, V> ordered = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();
  // Mapping the key to the order.
  Map<K, Integer> reorder = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();
  // The next position.
  AtomicInteger next = new AtomicInteger(0);

  @Override
  public V get(Object o) {
    return ordered.get(reorder.get(o));
  }

}
```

You would have to decide what you need to happen if you add to the same key twice. Which position should the value be in, the original position or the new position? Should the original one be removed?